# set widget on same position for all screens sizes

Tags: flutter, stack, position, offset

I am creating an app in which user can upload their floor plan and then add a draggable widget on that plan and resize it. So I did everything all works fine for me. Now the only issue is that I have stored the position of that draggable area and stored it in the database. So Once I fetch the position from the database and display again so based on different device sizes the position on the widget has been changed below is my code.

```
Widget areaWidget(){
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").where("floorPlanId", isEqualTo: controller.floorPlanId).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError){
          return Container();
        }
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          if(snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty){
            controller.lstArea = AreaListModel.fromJson(snapshot.requireData.docs).areaList;
            return Stack(
              children: [
                for(int i = 0; i < controller.lstArea.length; i++)
                  ResizebleWidget(
                    height: controller.lstArea[i].areaHeight,
                    width: controller.lstArea[i].areaWidth,
                    top: controller.lstArea[i].top, // this is fetched from DB
                    left: controller.lstArea[i].left,  // this is fetched from DB
                    topLeftOnDrag: (height, width, top, left, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: height, areaWidth: width, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: top, left: left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": height,
                        "areaWidth": width,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": top,
                        "left": left
                      });
                    },
                    topMiddleOnDrag: (height, top, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: height, areaWidth: controller.lstArea[i].areaWidth, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: top, left: controller.lstArea[i].left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": height,
                        "areaWidth": controller.lstArea[i].areaWidth,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": top,
                        "left": controller.lstArea[i].left
                      });
                    },
                    topRightOnDrag: (height, width, top, left, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: height, areaWidth: width, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: top, left: left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": height,
                        "areaWidth": width,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": top,
                        "left": left
                      });
                    },
                    centerRightOnDrag: (width, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: controller.lstArea[i].areaHeight, areaWidth: width, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: controller.lstArea[i].top, left: controller.lstArea[i].left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": controller.lstArea[i].areaHeight,
                        "areaWidth": width,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": controller.lstArea[i].top,
                        "left": controller.lstArea[i].left
                      });
                    },
                    bottomRightOnDrag: (height, width, top, left, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: height, areaWidth: width, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: top, left: left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": height,
                        "areaWidth": width,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": top,
                        "left": left
                      });
                    },
                    bottomCenterOnDrag: (height, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: height, areaWidth: controller.lstArea[i].areaWidth, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: controller.lstArea[i].top, left: controller.lstArea[i].left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": height,
                        "areaWidth": controller.lstArea[i].areaWidth,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": controller.lstArea[i].top,
                        "left": controller.lstArea[i].left
                      });
                    },
                    bottomLeftOnDrag: (height, width, top, left, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: height, areaWidth: width, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: top, left: left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": height,
                        "areaWidth": width,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": top,
                        "left": left
                      });
                    },
                    leftCenterOnDrag: (width, left, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: controller.lstArea[i].areaHeight, areaWidth: width, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: controller.lstArea[i].top, left: left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": controller.lstArea[i].areaHeight,
                        "areaWidth": width,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": controller.lstArea[i].top,
                        "left": left
                      });
                    },
                    centerCenterOnDrag: (top, left, initX, initY){
                      final areaData = AreaModel(areaHeight: controller.lstArea[i].areaHeight, areaWidth: controller.lstArea[i].areaWidth, areaId: controller.lstArea[i].areaId, areaName: controller.lstArea[i].areaName, areaX: initX, areaY: initY, createdAt: controller.lstArea[i].createdAt, floorPlanId: controller.lstArea[i].floorPlanId, top: top, left: left);
                      controller.lstArea[controller.lstArea.indexWhere((element) => element.areaId == controller.lstArea[i].areaId)] = areaData;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("floor_areas").doc(controller.lstArea[i].areaId).update({
                        "areaHeight": controller.lstArea[i].areaHeight,
                        "areaWidth": controller.lstArea[i].areaWidth,
                        "areaX": initX,
                        "areaY": initY,
                        "top": top,
                        "left": left
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      controller.lstArea[i].areaName!,
                      style: primaryTextStyleSemiBold(),
                    ),
                  )  
              ],
            );
          }
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
```

but based on screen sizes the position is changed so is there any way in which I can set it to the same position on each and every device?

I am attaching a screenshot of the output for two different size devices.

[This is the Screen of an Android Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm0fj.png)

[This is the screen of iOS Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEbOT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm throwing dart in the dark here(No pun intended) but instead statically setting position of the box which will be different for different screen sizes as you see, take the ration of screen width & height to position which user has set.

For example, let's your Offset is (200,200) then your dxRatio will be `200/MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.width` and dyRatio will be `200/MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.height`.
here you can also use `LayOutBuilder`.

Now, whenever you are positioning your widget multiple screen height and width with these ratios and they should be positioned at same place for different devices.

```
Positioned(
 left: dxRatio * screenWidth,
 top: dyRatio * screenHeight,
 child: ...
),
```

but here you have to take care of box size because bigger boxes might get cut off.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but still can you explain to me in more detail I tried with x and y positions with screen width and height but did not get desired output.

Comment: My OffSet Ratio is as below

 dxRatio: `309` and 
dyRatio: `433.6666564941406`

so how can i set this?

Comment: @VishalParmar dxRatio should always be between 0 and 1 because you are dividing a point in your screen with max height and width of your device.

Comment: so if you get ratio like 0.5 then left should be 0.5 * screenWidth

Comment: Okay Let me try this